# I need the print statement to stay in the If-loop so it is conditional, but out of the for loop so it doesn't repeat a ton of times

Tags: python, loops, break

Im currently using a for loop.
it iterates through a bunch of commands
and at the end, I want it to print something.
within this for loop, is a if-else statement.

I use break to break out the if- statement, then it goes straight to the else portion.

```
for x in list:
   if x is 1:
      do a bunch of commands
      break
   else:
      do a bunch of other commands
print 'Success'
```

I need the print statement to stay in the If-loop so it is conditional, but out of the for loop so it doesn't repeat a ton of times.
any ideas?

I want it to print 'Success' when ONLY when x does not equal 1. But only once at the end.

Comment: Indent the print statement to the 2rd level (2 indents, 0 based)

Comment: Use a flag. Mark it as True when you think it's time to say success. At the end, check and print

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a *flag* -- a variable that you set to indicate that an event occurred (in this case, that the `else` branch was reached).

```
success = False
for x in list:
   if x is 1:
      do a bunch of commands
      break
   else:
      do a bunch of other commands
      success = True

if success:
    print 'Success'
```

What's happening here is that the `else` case may be reached multiple times in the loop, setting the success variable to `True` (potentially) multiple times. The `if` statement at the end checks if the flag is `True` at the end, so `'Success'` is printed at most once.

Comment: Thanks mate, I got it to work. I first tried your solution, but it didn't work. However, I then added a statement "success = False" on the first condition of the if statement and it worked perfectly. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a flag in this case, python have you covered, use the `for` `else`

```
for x in list:
  if x is 1:
      # do a bunch of commands
      break
  else:
      # do a bunch of other commands
else:
    # only if we didn't break from the loop (no 1 in the list)
    print 'Success'
```

Answer (score 0):

## must set flag

flag = 0

def findlength(s):
    length = len(s)
    for p in password:
        if(length >= 6):
            flagA = 1
        else:
            flagA = 0

```
return flagA
```

def findupper(u):
    for p in password:
        if(p.isupper() == 1):
            flagB = 0

```
    else:
        flagB = 1

return flagB
```

def findlower(l):
    for p in password:
        if(p.islower()):
            flagC = 0

```
    else:
        flagC = 1

return flagC
```

def findnumber(d):
    for p in password:
        if(p.isdigit()):
            flagD = 1

```
    else:
        flagD = 0
return flagD
```

Comment: What does this answer have to do with the problem?